# Problem with error in UITableView.scrollToBottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm starting developer in Swift and I have a problem with error in TableView. I don't know how replicate this error. I tried many solutions and nothing.

My crashlytics error:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds section (2) when there are only 2 sections. Table view: <UITableView: 0x105038000; frame = (0 0; 375 524.5); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28322c810>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283cffe60>; contentOffset: {0, 723.5}; contentSize: {375, 1248}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Fotka.MessagesViewController: 0x1047ae870>>
```

First I secured against exceeding the value:

```
 if (self.numberOfSections > lastIndexPath.section && self.numberOfRows(inSection: lastIndexPath.section) > lastIndexPath.row ) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
                }
            }
```

And Fail, still are errors. Now I'll try with do-catch (out of my curiosity if it will work).

```
private var lastIndexPath: IndexPath? {
        guard numberOfSections > 0 else { return nil }

        do {
            let lastSection = numberOfSections - 1
            let numberOfRowsInLastSection = numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection)

            guard numberOfRowsInLastSection > 0 else { return nil }
            let lastRow = numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1

            return IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: lastSection)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        do {
            guard let lastIndexPath = self.lastIndexPath else { return }

            if (self.numberOfSections > lastIndexPath.section && self.numberOfRows(inSection: lastIndexPath.section) > lastIndexPath.row ) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    try? self.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Catch scroll error")
        }
    }
```

And execute:

```
  do {
            try tableView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        } catch {
            print("Error with scroll")
        }
```

Result: Still are errors.

Why even do-catch don't stop this error?

Add the code where is defining and using a section:

MessagesViewController: https://pastebin.com/1Kj537W7

MessagesViewModel: https://pastebin.com/gmPeZ5sJ

I cant't add all code application because this is a company app.

Comment: Are you adding sections while you are scrolling? Please share your data source code.

Comment: please read and cosider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. if you want help, give us copyable runnable code, which reproduces the error. else we can just guess. my guess is, you are changing the number of sections in a wrong way....

Comment: I cant't add all code application because this is a company app.
I added 2 files where is using a section.